# Zooming in/out on Android Webview without a set limit

Tags: android, webview, svg, android-webview, zooming

In my current project I need my users to be able to scroll over and zoom in on large SVG
Images. A major problem i encountered though, is the limit the android WebView class puts on zooming in and out. Is there any way I can remove or change these limits to my own likings?
The standard zoom controls do not seem to support releasing these boundries.

If my question is unclear, or if I need to elaborate on my question do not hesitate to ask.

Greets,
Wottah

Comment: Do you need this to work in general or on a specific Android flavour? I'm asking because the `WebView`'s zooming implementation has been changed around quite a bit over de different releases. You should be able to use reflection to bypass this 'limitation', but better prepare yourself for a whole bunch of different cases if you want to make it work on a range of devices/OS versions.

Comment: Well I need it to work on ICS(4.0.3). and preferably on both tablet devices and smartphones. I am currently testing my application on an Asus EEE transformer prime tablet. But I would like my app to work on devices like the Samsung Galaxy SII as well. is there no single solution that works for all android devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one seems to have come up with a different solution than using reflection - I'm not aware of any alternatives at this point - I wrote up a quick code snippet that illustrates how to bypass the upper limit on the zoom-in action.

Note that the code below will only work on ICS, and possibly Honeycomb, but I currently don't have a tablet lying around to inspect if the inner workings rely on the same `ZoomManager` class. Gingerbread, Froyo and Eclair all appear to implement the zooming functionality more or less directly in the `WebView` class. With the example below it should be fairly easy to add some code to also take those operating systems into account.

```
// just set an Activity's content view to a single WebView for this test
WebView mWebview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(mWebview);

// retrieve the ZoomManager from the WebView
Class<?> webViewClass = mWebview.getClass();
Field mZoomManagerField = webViewClass.getDeclaredField("mZoomManager");
mZoomManagerField.setAccessible(true);
Object mZoomManagerInstance = mZoomManagerField.get(mWebview);

// modify the "default max zoom scale" value, which controls the upper limit
// and set it to something very large; e.g. Float.MAX_VALUE
Class<?> zoomManagerClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.ZoomManager");
Field mDefaultMaxZoomScaleField = zoomManagerClass.getDeclaredField("mDefaultMaxZoomScale");
mDefaultMaxZoomScaleField.setAccessible(true);
mDefaultMaxZoomScaleField.set(mZoomManagerInstance, Float.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: that is exactly what i needed! Thanks!! You just managed to fix one of the major issues of my internship project ^^.I do not need my application to work on versions lower than ICS, as some key features of my app are only implemented on 4.0 . I've pondered for ages on this issue. May I ask how you got the information needed to edit the webview class like this? (this is my first android project, and I'm really getting into it)

Comment: Send me a copy of your final report and we call it even. ;) In terms of where/how I found the information for this approach: I highly recommend [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/) when it comes to Android sources. I just had a look through the inner workings of `WebView`, which then led me to `ZoomManager`. The last key ingredient is having descriptive variable names, which, fortunately, Android tends to have. Once you have these details, implementing the actual reflection is relatively simple, as you can see above.

Comment: I see, this helps putting it all into context. as far as the report goes: it will be in dutch , so I will see what i can do xD.

Comment: @Wottah: Call it a coincidence, but that actually won't be a problem at all, since I'm Dutch myself. :)

Comment: @PointerNull: Android KitKat and above (19+) no longer uses webkit (but a Chromium-based WebView implementation instead), so it's to be expected proposed hack no longer works. You'll have to dive into more recent source code to see if an alternative approach exists. Do note that the original code was only meant for research purposes - you should *not* rely on it in production code, *ever*.